# How to make "Show windows side by side" and "Show windows stacked" work in Windows 10 the same way it does in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, window

In Windows 7 this worked perfectly: open 3 windows, right-click the taskbar, click "Show windows side by side", and it arranges them into 3 columns, 1 row. In Windows 10 however this becomes 1 column of 3 rows, in the left third of the screen. I guess technically the top and the bottom of windows are their "sides"  but this is wildly counter-intuitive and absolutely not what I want.

Interestingly enough, "Show windows stacked" gives the same exact result. Technically the windows are stacked, but only in the left third of the desktop, not filling the entire width of the screen. Sometimes I need this arrangement also, and it's broken too.

I tried following older advice like toggling the options of what happens when I snap windows, and killing/restarting Windows Shell Experience Host and Explorer, but that either doesn't help, or gives even weirder results like filling the left third of the screen with 2 windows and then the middle third with one window in the top half.

How do I revert this new behavior to that of Windows 7? (Please note the older solutions might not be working anymore with the most recent updates)